# Save jzy3d Chart in PDF using DynamicReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports, jzy3d

I'm using [DynamicReports](http://www.dynamicreports.org/) API to create a PDF report displaying the results of my `Java` application (tables and charts).
One of the chart I have to display is a `3D Surface Plot` build using [jzy3d 0.9.0](http://www.jzy3d.org/download-0.9.php).

Here is my code:

```
import static net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports.*;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.examples.Templates;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.examples.complex.invoice.InvoiceDesign;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.examples.complex.sales.SalesDesign;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.constant.HorizontalImageAlignment;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.constant.HorizontalTextAlignment;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.constant.PageType;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.constant.VerticalImageAlignment;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.constant.VerticalTextAlignment;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.chart.PieChartBuilder;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.component.ComponentBuilder;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.component.ComponentBuilders;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.component.TextFieldBuilder;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.style.FontBuilder;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.style.StyleBuilder;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.constant.PageOrientation;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.datasource.DRDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.export.Exporters;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.column.TextColumnBuilder;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.component.HorizontalListBuilder;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import com.fairdynamics.components.FDPalette;
import com.fairdynamics.components.FDGlassPane;
import com.fairdynamics.components.FDOptionPane;
import fairdynamics.lyrica.UI_VisualAnalytics.UIRespondersHeatMap.HeatMapDetails;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import org.jzy3d.maths.*;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.builder.*;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.builder.concrete.OrthonormalGrid;
import org.jzy3d.colors.ColorMapper;
import org.jzy3d.colors.colormaps.ColorMapRainbow;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.primitives.Shape;
import org.jzy3d.chart.Chart;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.rendering.canvas.Quality;
import org.jzy3d.chart.ChartLauncher;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.builder.Mapper;

public class UI_ReportBuilder3 extends JasperReportBuilder{
    protected final FontBuilder font18 = stl.font("Roboto Light",false,false,18);
    protected final FontBuilder font16 = stl.font("Roboto Light",false,false,16);
    protected final FontBuilder font14 = stl.font("Roboto Light",false,false,14);
    protected final FontBuilder font12 = stl.font("Roboto Light",false,false,12);
    protected final FontBuilder font10 = stl.font("Roboto Light",false,false,10);
    protected final StyleBuilder titleStyle = stl.style(font12).setVerticalTextAlignment(VerticalTextAlignment.TOP).setForegroundColor(FDPalette.primaryColor);
    protected final StyleBuilder mainTitleStyle = stl.style(font18).setVerticalTextAlignment(VerticalTextAlignment.TOP).setForegroundColor(FDPalette.primaryColor);
    protected final StyleBuilder subTitleStyle = stl.style(font14).setVerticalTextAlignment(VerticalTextAlignment.TOP).setForegroundColor(FDPalette.primaryColor);
    protected final StyleBuilder footerStyle = stl.style(font10).setVerticalTextAlignment(VerticalTextAlignment.MIDDLE).setForegroundColor(FDPalette.secondaryText);
    protected final StyleBuilder colStyle = stl.style(font12).setVerticalTextAlignment(VerticalTextAlignment.MIDDLE);   

    public UI_ReportBuilder3() {        
        try{
            this
            .setTemplate(Templates.reportTemplate)
            .setPageFormat(PageType.A4,PageOrientation.PORTRAIT)
            .setPageMargin(margin(40))
            .pageFooter(
                    cmp.text("Footer").setStyle(footerStyle).setHorizontalTextAlignment(HorizontalTextAlignment.CENTER)
                )
            .title(
                    cmp.horizontalList().add(
                        cmp.text("TITLE").setStyle(mainTitleStyle).setHorizontalTextAlignment(HorizontalTextAlignment.LEFT)
                    )
                    .setFixedHeight(32)
                )
            .summary(
                    cmp.multiPageList(cmp.image(createHeatMap().screenshot())
                        )
                )
            .show()
            ;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private org.jzy3d.chart.Chart createHeatMap(){          
        // Define a function to plot
        Mapper mapper = new Mapper() {
            public double f(double x, double y) {
                return 10 * Math.sin(x / 10) * Math.cos(y / 20) * x;
            }
        };

        // Define range and precision for the function to plot
        Range range = new Range(-150, 150);
        int steps = 50;

        // Create a surface drawing that function
        org.jzy3d.plot3d.primitives.Shape surface = Builder.buildOrthonormal(new OrthonormalGrid(range, steps, range, steps), mapper);
        surface.setColorMapper(new ColorMapper(new ColorMapRainbow(), surface.getBounds().getZmin(), surface.getBounds().getZmax(), new org.jzy3d.colors.Color(1, 1, 1, .5f)));
        surface.setFaceDisplayed(true);
        surface.setWireframeDisplayed(false);
        surface.setWireframeColor(org.jzy3d.colors.Color.BLACK);

        // Create a chart and add the surface
        org.jzy3d.chart.Chart chart = new org.jzy3d.chart.Chart(Quality.Advanced);
        chart.getScene().getGraph().add(surface);

        return chart;
    }

}
```

This code works only if I call the method `ChartLauncher.openChart(chart)` (consequently opening a frame with the chart displayed in) from `createHeatMap()`
before returning `chart`, otherwise `createHeatMap().screenshot()` always returns `null`.
But what if I need to create and export a PDF of this chart without displaying the chart itself in my java application?

**NOTE:** if possible, I'd prefer to use [jzy3d 0.9.0](http://www.jzy3d.org/download-0.9.php) and not [jzy3d 0.9.1](http://www.jzy3d.org/download-0.9.1.php) because otherwise I should modify a lot of code already written and tested.

Comment: Convert it to java.awt.Image and pass it as such?

Comment: What should I convert to Image? I mean, the `org.jzy3d.chart.Chart` class already provides a `screenshot()` method, but this method return null if the chart is not displayed properly. The problem is that I don't want to display the chart.

Comment: I have no experience with jzy3d chart only in jasper report. From jasper reports point of view you need to pass Image, that's why I suggested to isolate away the problem of jasper-reports and only concentrate on create a method that returns a java.awt.Image of your chart (screenshot, draw to g2, save to file???), the best way to do this using jzy3d however I do not know.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the hint. Let's forget about `jzy3d` and only consider a common `java.awt.Component`. How can I get a `java.awt.Image` from it when it is not displayed (preferred size = 0 , 0)?

Comment: Also that seems hacky, is there no standard way to save the image to file, who draws the image to on the components grafics g2?. I would try to either intercept this or pass another Grafics g2 to the library... but then again I do not know how the lib works..

Comment: If you like to hack maybe try to override the setVisibile(true) in the chart component (hence jzy3d, thinks the component is open but its not)... same with getSize() etc... but I would try to figure out how it draws the cart on component (the g2 implementation) and then pass an Image's g2 instead of compoent g2.

Comment: I see other subclasses of Chart http://doc.jzy3d.org/javadoc/0.9.1/jzy3d-api/, are you sure you need a Component... maybe GraphChart()  does the trick???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to capture the screenshot in this way:

```
Chart c = AWTChartComponentFactory.chart(Quality.Nicest,org.jzy3d.chart.factories.IChartComponentFactory.Toolkit.offscreen);
c.screenshot();
BufferedImage i = ((OffscreenCanvas)c.getCanvas()).getRenderer()).getLastScreenshotImage();
```